# Issue with Designing For Multiple Screens Android

Tags: android, xml, layout

Eclipse has provided us with different qualifiers like size, ratio , etc. So when I select a qualifier, it provides us with the right emulator screen to make our layout. But are these emulators screen loaded under the right layout folder? I dont understand, how **Nexus 10 which is a xlarge screen size** is loaded when I load the activity_main under the **Normal layout** folder?

am I blindly arranging these layouts? Because before this, I had arranged all layouts perfectly and when I went to run it on a Virtual Device, it looked a complete mess. I looked at the xml files and they were completely in the wrong places.

I have used qualifiers like : *normal-long, normal-notlong, large-long, large-notlong, small-long, small-notlong, xlarge-long, xlarge-notlong,*

Should I change the qualifiers? Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be some kind of a bug in eclipse, with layout-large etc not being used much now. 
I would advise you to try using smallest width qualifiers.

also, if you would like more accurate emulation, you could look into genymotion emulators
http://www.genymotion.com/

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problems. I use the layout-normal, layout-small/-large etc. These folders though are deprecated and android recommends using the swdp like layout-sw600. I still use the small/normal/large/xlarge folders but eclipse had a bug which caused the wrong display to open for normal layouts. Updated my adt plugin fixed it for me

Comment: Okay, I understand I should use layout-sw*dp* qualifiers. But this defines the smallest width size. My layout design may change according to the height. So any solution to that? Will, using qualifiers like sw600-long or sw600-notlong solve the height issue?

Comment: @pblead26 you can use other qualifiers. Please check http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html for more info. Also try using small/normal etc after you update your adt plugin